# Tag ancora e hover não funcionam em um drop-menu?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando criar um drop-menu, mas a tag `<a>` e `:hover` não funciona, quando passo ou mouse por cima fica como se não tivesse nada.

```css
#menu-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #111111;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu li a {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font: bold 100% Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu li {
  width: 10%;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: background 1s ease;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  transition: 2s ease;
  background: #00b2ff;
}

.menu li a:not(:hover) {
  transition: 3s ease;
}

.menu li ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.menu li ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  position: relative;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #00b2ff;
}

.menu li ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu li ul li:hover {
  background: #00b2ff;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-block">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>NOTICIAS</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <p>PAGINA</p>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>SOBRE</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>CONTATO</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: O que seria `a:not(:hover)`? Qual exatamente é a parte que não funcionou?

Comment: a:not(:hover) é para dar tempo no transition quando tirar o mouse, oque não funcionou foi que aparece o submenu, mas quando passo o mouse por cima não acontece nada, o link que fica na ancora não aparece e a transição do submenu não acontece.

Comment: Oq ue vc deveria ver é que existem vários `display` no `.menu li a` e existem tambem dois `.menu li a` no seu css.

Comment: esse .menu li a funciona mas o .menu li ul li a não.

Comment: remova o display none da 3° linha do css, dê um overflow:hidden na li para que ela não gere um scroll, e quando houver o Hover na primeira li desta lista ".menu > li:hover" {height: !heightTotalDaLista}, aconselho dar o height com javascript, assim você não corre o risco de colocar um valor impreciso

Comment: Existem ai diversos, mas diversos problemas.. Tanto no css quanto no HTML, para alguém responder essa pergunta com seu próprio código vai precisar praticamente refaze-lo.

Comment: @Caymmi, conseguiu resolver seu problema?